# paginate related model in laravel

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

This seems a simple problem but I can't find a solution for this.
I'm trying to paginate a related model this way:

```
$store=Store::findOrFail(1);
$reviews=$store->reviews()->whereRaw('comment IS NOT NULL')->simplePaginate(10);
```

`$reviews` will be an instance of `LightWeightPaginator`, but current page is set to 2, trying of changing page in view , is not working too.

I'm wondering how you paginate a relationship from a model.

Answer (score 0):

With related models, you need to tell `simplePaginate()` how many results you would like per page.

For example:

```
$reviews=$store->reviews()->whereRaw('comment IS NOT NULL')->simplePaginate(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

> There are several ways to paginate items. The simplest is by using the paginate method on the query builder or an Eloquent query.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results